# Open CL clEnqueueReadBuffer execute time

Tags: opencl, execution-time

im writing open cl flocking and i have strange issue. Before Kernel Execute, clEnqueueReadBuffer read from gpu mem to program mem 20000 array float with no problem, very fast, but after kernel execute which did some operation on that passed array, readbuffer last too long (~150 ms). Why? In both case array was filled with data. What possibly wrong my kernel doing? (that passed array is __global).

Comment: how was the gpu memory filled with data before a kernel is executed?

Answer (score 2):

`clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` doesn't actually launch the kernels, it "enqueues" them. The OpenCL implementation is free to start kernels whenever it sees fit (in this case, when you ask to read the results, since it needs to run the kernel to know the results).

You can, however, force the implementation to start the kernels via `clFinish`.

In your case, the 150ms delay is, in fact, the time taken for the kernel to run.

If you call `clFinish` between execute and second read, it will work.